# Timer ticker Event is delay on some computer

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer

My .Net Project I insert Timer and set Interval = 100
Textbox will set value every 0.5 second by using below event :

```
Timer1.Interval = 100
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        textboxWeight.Text= m_dblWG '* 1000
        textboxQty.Text= m_dblWG / IIf(m_dblWeightPerPcs = 0, 1, dblWeightPerPcs)
 End Sub
```

But It's work when I run this program on my desctop but when I run it on user's computer which is low spec, it's delay 3 second.

Comment: Possibly because it is low spec. If you want performance you probably need a high spec machine.

Comment: Do you think if I will try use thread for resolve this problem?

Comment: No, it sounds like the hard drive is going nuts to launch your app. That's what's making the 3 second delay. Starting a thread will just make it worse. Each thread allocates over 1MB of RAM just t get started.

Comment: If it's 3 seconds for every update, then I don't think it's the disk. If just at start then, yes, there's a bunch of overhead to get the program loaded. It also looks like you're updating every 100 ms (keeping in mind that's just an approximation) since there's nothing in your tick routine to ignore the other 4 tick events.